# Must an AES plain text to be encrypted be 128bit

Tags: encryption, aes, rijndael

I am reading up on AES, but most say it takes a Plain text of 128bits so it can be used in a 4*4 matrix each of 1 byte where the basic operations like sub byte, shift row, mix column, would be performed on them. Must the plain text be 128bits? according to this [website](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) which allows one to run AES online. I used a plain text **"big"** and it still got encrypted. the text big cannot fill the 4*4 matrix, so what happens to the remaining space in the matrix ?.

Comment: AES is primitive where it has a 128-bit block size. Therefore the input must be 128-bit. AES like any block cipher must be used with the proper [blockcipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) where the input can be plaintext or counter. See the answer for the modes

Comment: @kelalaka in lame man term, must the input plaintext be 128bit also?

Comment: Think of AES encryption as a black box with a mode of operations that can be adjusted from the outside. Then when you enter an input of any size then it produces output. If CBC or ECB is used then the black box adjusts the message size the message is padded to make sure that it is multiple of 128 for AES and this always increases the output size. This padding is usually performed out of sight of the user and the same happens in the decryption, too. If CTR, OFB, or CFB mode is used then there is no padding so you will not see a size increment from the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a 'block' mode (ECB or CBC) then the plaintext needs to be padded out to a multiple of the block size (128 bits), generally with 0 bits (though other schemes can be used)

If you use a 'stream' mode (CFB, OFB, or CTR), there's no need to pad out the input -- it can be any length (in bits) and the resulting ciphertext will be the same length.